# having trouble with a query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return rows for pet depending on the available values for country, province and city. I have tried putting %country%, %province%, %city%...

```
 WHERE
 pet LIKE "Grey parrot"
 AND
(country LIKE '$country'
 or province LIKE '$province'
 or city like '$city' )
```

I also tried this:

```
 WHERE
 country LIKE '$country'
 or province LIKE '$province'
 or city like '$city'
  AND (pet like 'Grey parrot')
```

if values for $country...then return all Grey parrots in that country...

if values for $country and $province then return all Grey parrots in that country and province.

if values for $country, $province, $city then show all Grey parrots in that country, province and city.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, and please read about data binding.

Comment: Should be a more simple method than that...I just want the query to use the values at hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect and this is a SQL error

if values for $country...then return all Grey parrots in that country...

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE country='$country' 
    AND pet='Grey Parrot'
```

if values for $country and $province then return all Grey parrots in that country and province.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE province = '$province' 
    AND country = '$country' 
    AND pet='Grey Parrot'
```

if values for $country, $province, $city then show all Grey parrots in that country, province and city.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE province = '$province' 
    AND country = '$country'
    AND city='$city' 
    AND pet='Grey Parrot'
```

Comment: Ok thanks...so I will have to do 3 separate queries.

Comment: @user3005687 it is possible to do it in one query where you 'assemble' the query based on the number of inputs but it's a lot cleaner and easier to maintain by spreading it over 3 queries.